# java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, simpledateformat

I am able to insert the date the insert the data into the database, but when I tried to fetch the data out and show it in the jDateChooser, it showed up the error as the topic stated. why?

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.util.Date;
```

these are the packages I imported in

```
private void DisplayTable(){
        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/java_his_db","root","");
               String sql = "select * from reservation";
               PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();
               jTable_reservation.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
               
        }catch (Exception e) {
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                               }
    }
```

this is my private void to show the data into jTable

```
private void jTable_reservationMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_reservation.getModel();

    int rowInd = jTable_reservation.getSelectedRow();

    roomID.setText(model.getValueAt(rowInd, 0).toString());
    customerID.setText(model.getValueAt(rowInd, 1).toString());

    try {
        Date selectin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)model.getValueAt(rowInd, 3));
        jDateChooser_in.setDate(selectin);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                           }
 
}
```

these are the code I used to fetch the data into text fields.

the catch exception then showed the error above whenever I clicked one row from the table.

***java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String (java.sql.Date is in module java.sql of loader 'platform'; java.lang.string is in module java.base of loader 'boostrap')***

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, it is clear that the following call returns an object of type `java.sql.Date` which can not cast into a `String`.

```
model.getValueAt(rowInd, 3)
```

Simply, do it as follows:

```
java.util.Date selectin = model.getValueAt(rowInd, 3);
```

If you want to format it into some specific pattern (`String`), you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to do so e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = sdf.format(selectin);
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

You can use [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) to switch from the `java.util.Date` to `java.time.Instant` which is a type from the modern date-time API.

```
Instant instant = selectin.toInstant();
LocalDate dateSelectin = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
String strDateSelectin = dateSelectin.toString();
```

Replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with the applicable timezone e.g. `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")` as per your requirement.

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.